# Setting up a GlassFish server on NetBeans

Tags: java

I am trying to move on to the Java EE as well as Web-Services and JSF applications. Most of these require a server. I know about installing Glassfish from Tool menu. However, I am having the same problem even though I installed the Glassfish a couple times.

Heres is the output window from the run-deploy of welcomeSOAP on NetBeans:

```
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting GlassFish Server 3+
Could not connect to admin listener for GlassFish Server 3+.
Verify that NetBeans can make outbound connections to localhost:4848
C:\Documents and Settings\NetBeansProjects\WelcomSOAP\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1023: Deployment error: Could not connect to admin listener for GlassFish Server 3+.
Verify that NetBeans can make outbound connections to localhost:4848
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 minutes 3 seconds)
```

I have unblocked the NetBeans several times from the firewall...so I do not think that is the problem. The other thing is that the Glassfish 3+ output on my NetBeans is showing a ton of errors..like 10 feet of them on my screen.

And finally my NetBeans issued a pop-up window saying:

```
Verify that NetBeans can make outbound connections to localhost:4848
```

Comment: Have you checked the server log? Did the server start? Do you see a line like: Created HTTP listener [admin-listener] on host/port [0.0.0.0:4848], maybe the port used is different?